# shellcode resutado "Segmentation fault"

Tags: c, assembly

Bom tenho um arquivo chamado teste.asm com o codigo (para windows):

```
section .text
    global _main
    extern _printf

msg:
    db "%d", 0

_main:
    mov eax, 10
    add eax, 20

    push eax
    push msg
    call _printf
    add esp, 8
    ret
```

compilando usando o nasm: `nasm -f win32 teste.asm -o teste.o`
e depois usando o `objdump` do `gcc` tenho o seguinte:

```
00000000 <msg>:
   0:   25 64 00 b8 0a          and    $0xab80064,%eax

00000003 <_main>:
   3:   b8 0a 00 00 00          mov    $0xa,%eax
   8:   83 c0 14                add    $0x14,%eax
   b:   50                      push   %eax
   c:   68 00 00 00 00          push   $0x0
  11:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   16 <_main+0x13>
  16:   83 c4 08                add    $0x8,%esp
  19:   c3                      ret
```

usando agora no arquivo `shellcode.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char shellcode[] = "\x25\x64\x00\xb8\x0a\xb8\x0a\x00\x00\x00\x83\xc0\x14\x50\x68\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x83\xc4\x08\xc3";

int main( void )
{
  int (*func)();
  func = (int (*)())shellcode;

  (int)(*func)();
}
```

compilando: `gcc shellcode.c -o main`
e executando: `./main`
tenho o seguinte:

> Segmentation fault

alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

O código binário do shellcode, declarado na variável `shellcode[]`, fica armazenado na memória
em uma página destinada a dados, portanto, sem permissão para execução de código
(somente leitura+escrita).

Quando o programa chama a função `func()`, que aponta para a página de dados, ocorre um erro de
segmentação (*General Protection Fault*), devido à falta de privilégio de execução na página
de destino.

Caso você queira apenas testar o shellcode, é necessário:

- Incluir o *header* Windows.h
- Alocar uma página de memória e atribuir a permissão de execução+escrita a esta página
- Copiar o código binário que está na variável `shellcode[]` para a página alocada
- Apontar a função para o início dessa página
- Chamar a função

O código (comentado) fica da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Incluir o header Windows.h
#include <Windows.h>

const char shellcode[] = "\x25\x64\x00\xb8\x0a\xb8\x0a\x00\x00\x00\x83\xc0\x14\x50\x68\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x83\xc4\x08\xc3";

int main( void )
{
    int (*func)();
    
    // Cria um ponteiro para a página de memória que será alocada
    LPVOID page;

    // Aloca a página de memória com permissão de escrita e execução
    page = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 4096, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    // Copia o shellcode para a página alocada
    CopyMemory(page, shellcode, 256);

    // Aponta func para a página e não para a variável shellcode
    func = (int (*)())page;

    // Chama a função    
    (int)(*func)();

    // Desaloca a página
    VirtualFree(page, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    return 0;
}
```

No código assembly, você declarou a função `_printf` como extern, porém, ao compilar o programa, o *linker* não tem como descobrir ou alterar o endereço desta função, pois ela está embutida dentro do shellcode, por isso, ao chamar o programa em assembly ele irá dar erro.

A dica aqui é evitar declarar funções externas.

Comment: Ok. Obrigado !!